# Variables not working in included file in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, include

I want include all part of home page. For example fetch site title from data base is working in `header.php` but when I include `header.php` in `index.php` I face error that variable I passed to my view file with controller are unknown.

Controller :

```
$this->load->model('mobshop');
$data['title']=$this->mobshop->get_title();
$this->load->view('header',$data);
```

View file:

```
<h1>
<?php echo $title['site_name']; ?>
</h1>
```

Comment: can you `var_dump($this->mobshop->get_title())`?

Comment: Is the "View file" above header.php?

Comment: Is index.php the "Controller" shown above? If not, how/where are you "including" index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$this->mobshop->get_title()` returns a string, your view would simply be this.

```
<h1>
<?php echo $title; ?>
</h1>
```

If `get_title()` returns and array equivalent to this for example

```
$data['title'] = array('site name' => "My Site");
```

then you would use the syntax you have in the question.

In your question you say

> but when i include header.php in index.php ....

leads me to ask, do you literally mean using an `include` statement as in, `include 'header.php';`? If so, you might get better results by outputting views the "CodeIgniter way".

```
$this->load->view('header', $data);
$this->load->view('index'); //which is **not** a great name for a controller IMO
```

This way any variables in `$data` will also be visible to `index`.

Comment: this will work but i donw want load home page after submitting title just i want show messege for example " your site title has been update successfully"

Comment: @Farzaneh, That is not at all clear from the code you show or from the problem statement "Variables not working in included file in php codeigniter". Please edit your question to provide a better understanding of what you want to accomplish and what/where problems are occurring.